# How to create a preview with an opened keyboard in Android Compose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack, preview

I am working with Android Jetpack Compose and would like to create a preview in which the software keyboard is opened. I want to see how my UI layout behaves when the keyboard is present. Unfortunately, I haven't been able to find a built-in feature or modifier that directly supports displaying a preview with the keyboard open.

If there is no direct way to achieve this, I would like to know if there are any workarounds or techniques to simulate an opened keyboard in a Compose preview. I have come across the "ime" modifier, but I'm not sure how to use it effectively for this purpose.

Any guidance, examples, or code snippets demonstrating how to create a Compose preview with an opened keyboard or simulate the keyboard presence would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

The software keyboard will not be displayed if there is no composable that accepts text input, such as a TextField when it is focused.

You could potentially use a workaround where you define a TextField and set its alpha to 0f. Additionally, you will need to request focus on launch.

For example:

```
@Composable
fun MainView() {
    val focusRequester = remember {
        FocusRequester()
    }
    LaunchedEffect(key1 = Unit, block = {
        focusRequester.requestFocus()
    })
    Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(), contentAlignment = Alignment.Center){
        androidx.compose.material3.Text(text = "Trial text")
        OutlinedTextField(value = "", onValueChange = {}, modifier = Modifier.focusRequester(focusRequester).alpha(0f))
    }
}

@Preview
@Composable
fun MainPreview(){
    MainView()
}
```

**Sample Image**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/55kwR.png

Comment: I overlooked the "Run Preview" button in the top right corner of the preview. Unfortunately this does not behave like in the real app. It seems like it is not using android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" from the AndroidManifest. So the content moves around unlike in the actual app.

Beside that I would prefer if could show the keyboard in the preview without hitting the "Run Preview" button.